# How to Strip New Line

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use TextArea to provides user to type options with every single row. I want to Split these rows and insert these words to database row by row. I use Razor View Engine.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried splitting by `Environment.NewLine` ??

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how the string on the server side?

Comment: @RononDex No I haven't tried Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your controller

```
  string[] Options= form["option"].Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Source SO
Edit:
If you want to handle different types of line breaks in a text, you can use the ability to match more than one string. This will correctly split on either type of line break, and preserve empty lines and spacing in the text:

```
string[] lines = theText.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `StringReader` class
`ReadLine()` method

It is more elegant.